# Creating stored function in H2 on Win64

Tags: h2, flyway

I am getting an error in Win64 environment during creating a user-defined function. I am using flyway to execute the following simple script:

```
CREATE ALIAS TRANSLATE_NAME AS $$
String TRANSLATE_NAME(String value) {
  ...
return null;
}
$$
```

I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

17:10:38 ERROR (ApacheCommonsLog.java:51) - com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: 
Error executing statement at line 1: 
CREATE ALIAS TRANSLATE_NAME AS $$

String TRANSLATE_NAME(String value) {
return null;
}
$$
```

This appears ONLY on Win64, neither on 32-bit Linux or 32bit-Windows.

Any ideas? I would appreciate it! Please!

Log:

```
17:10:37 INFO (DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) - Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
17:10:37 INFO (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1374) - Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
17:10:38 INFO (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43) - Creating Metadata table: "PUBLIC"."schema_version"
17:10:38 INFO (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43) - Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
17:10:38 INFO (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43) - Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.1
17:10:38 INFO (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43) - Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.2
17:10:38 INFO (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43) - Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.3
17:10:38 INFO (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43) - Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.4
17:10:38 ERROR (ApacheCommonsLog.java:51) - com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 1: CREATE ALIAS TRANSLATE_NAME AS $$
String TRANSLATE_NAME(String value) {
    if (value.equals("Ilya")) {
        return "Юлия";
    }
    return null;
}
$$
17:10:38 ERROR (ApacheCommonsLog.java:51) - Caused by java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
17:10:38 INFO (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:444) - Destroying singletons in...
```

Comment: Please post a complete stack trace. Also where does CreateProcess error=2 come from?

Comment: Yes, please post the stack trace. Also, could you find out if "javac" is in the path, that means, what happens if you open a command prompt and type "javac" [Enter]? H2 needs a JDK either in the classpath (the tools.jar in the classpath), or "javac" needs to be available as an external process.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention! I have added log entries, will try to get more exceptions later. Database is in memory, mem mode, so i wonder - why it requires any file... I will check "javac" also later.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! javac was not in the PATH, because of JRE utilization, i think! You helped me a lot! Please, issue your answer - i'll accept it. I think it is not even an Win64 issue then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 needs a JDK either in the classpath (the tools.jar in the classpath), or `javac` needs to be available as an external process. To find out if `javac` is in the classpath, open a command prompt and type `javac` [Enter].

Answer (score 0):

In my case, JAVA_HOME was defined as an environment variable and was pointing to the wrong JRE (without a javac command). I deleted it as it was not longer required and that did the trick. While this is unlikely to be your particular scenario it proves that this is related to the environment variables resolving paths to jdks.